# dictionary - adding up the values(list) in a dictionary based on conditions

Tags: python

How can I calculate the total of values(list) for each key in the dictionary in the function given below?

I want to write a python function called:

```py
total_country_population(country_pop_dict, country_name)
```

**Parameters:**

- `country_pop_dict` is a dictionary containing countries and their populations over a period of time.
- `country_name` is the name of the country.

The function **returns** the total population of the parameter country in the dictionary.

An example of the function being called:

Given a dictionary named `pop_dict`:

```
pop_dict = {'Country_1':[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000],
            'Country_2': [6000, 7000, 8000],
            'Country_3':[65000] :}
print(total_country_population(pop_dict, 'Country_1'))
print(total_country_population(pop_dict, 'Country_2'))
print(total_country_population(pop_dict, 'Country_3'))
```

Expected result/output:

```
100000 #(10000 + 20000 + 30000 + 40000)
21000
65000
```

Comment: The whole function had several other aspects to it which I completed on my own, I just wanted to know the logic associated with values in a list assigned to a key and how we can perform operations on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def total_country_population(country_pop_dict, country_name):
    return sum(country_pop_dict[country_name])
```

Is what you are looking for? The population over time for each country is saved in a list, so you sum the given list and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a function as well:

```
for populations in pop_dict.values():
    print(sum(populations))
```